# extraction of tweets an storing

Tags: php, mongodb, twitter

```
<?php
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->twitter;
$collection = $db->tweets;
$screen_name = "learnmongo";
$twitter = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?";
$twitter .= "screen_name=" . $screen_name;
$curl = curl_init($twitter);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$usertimeline = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline);
foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
$collection->insert($item);
}

?>
```

execution of this code gives error message as invalid parameters to foreach().plzz reply and hep me to solve this problem

Comment: It looks like you haven't authenticated, which is required, and you're using the old API.  Might want to check out the Twitter documentation. EDIT: My bad... authentication isn't required, bu the old API issue still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [deprecated verion](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) of the Twitter API.  **Version 1.0 no longer works**, you need to use version 1.1. You need to use [version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) of the call.  The API URL has changed from:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

to

```
http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

Unfortunately the [new 1.1 version](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) requires authentication so your code will still not work until you implement an OAUTH solution for authentication.

Comment: actually i have acuired the authentication tokens but i don't know how to use it...can you suggest me the code please.

Comment: You are best using a Twitter PHP class such as tmhOAuth - https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth]..with Examples Here - https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples

Comment: Other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422879/best-twitter-php-library